# get date range from date of birth

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a peers page for my website and I am trying to get a query that can fetch users from the users table which is structured as `id, name, gender, dob`. The query should fetch the users relative to the logged user's date of birth, i.e users who's dob is either 2 years less or 3 years more than the logged user's dob. The dob in the table is structured like `1993-03-23`. I need help with the query so that it meets my requirements. This is a basic sample query.

```
$users = $db->query(
    'SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE users.id=:id',
    array(':id'=>$userid)
);
```

Comment: Hi! Kindly include your table structure, some sample data and your desired output. Thank you

Comment: @ErrBon I just edited it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? The query does not contain any condition to filter for a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You know logged user dob can use next approach:

```
<?php
$logged_user_dob = '1993-01-01';
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE dob BETWEEN DATE_SUB(:logged_user_dob, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(:logged_user_dob, INTERVAL 3 YEAR)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':logged_user_dob'=>'1993-01-01']);

$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_export($res);
```

[Share PHP code online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=0e917babfabbd5da6c514796cbc1211c&sqlses=b2ea7e7860fffb92babff50d9bbeb53c&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

In case you have only logged user id - use next query:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT tbl.* 
    FROM tbl 
    JOIN tbl AS tmp ON 
        tbl.dob BETWEEN DATE_SUB(tmp.dob, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(tmp.dob, INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
        AND tmp.id = :id
    WHERE tbl.id <> :id";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':id'=>2]);

$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_export($res);
```

[Run & test PHP code online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=937c5ef89274a237742d9e335038f6a3&sqlses=8756eea3a155c1334c80373d1e85d200&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: thanks I edited it to this, `$q = $db->query("SELECT name  FROM users WHERE dob BETWEEN DATE_SUB(:dob, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(:dob, INTERVAL 3 YEAR)", array(':dob'=>$dob, ':dob'=>$dob))`